# Why does TypeScript module re-exporting behave like lazy loading?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, export, lazy-loading

I'm currently using the following versions of tools:

- React-Native 71
- React 18.2
- TypeScript 4.8.3

In JavaScript, we have the mechanism of named re-export and re-exporting all the content of a module. For instance:

```
// foo.ts

console.log('JS see it')

export const myFunc = () => {
…
}
```

```
// index.ts
export * from 'foo'; // re-exporting everything
//  VS
export {myFunc} from 'foo'; // re-exporting only myFunc
```

Afterwards, I use this function in another module:

```
// myComponent.ts
...
import {myFunc} from './index';
myFunc();
```

I've noticed that when I perform the re-export of all the content of the module 'foo', I see the logs that I invoke in the 'foo' module when the application starts. However, when I do a named re-export, the logs don't appear until the first time I call the re-exported function.

This reminds me of lazy-loading module behavior.

Could you please explain why this is happening?